# Change bootstrap file input focus glow color in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, bootstrap-4

I have this file input that I would like to change the color of the blue glow when I select it.

[image]

```
<Form className='col-12'>
    <input type='file' className='custom-file-input' id='batch-file'
           onChange={e => this.setState({file: e.target.files[0], fileName: e.target.files[0].name})}/>
    <label className='custom-file-label' htmlFor='customFile'>{this.state.fileName}</label>
</Form>
```

Ive tried changing CSS to this:

```
input:focus, input[custom-file-input]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {
    border-color: $custom-orange;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px $custom-orange;
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

As I have seen in many examples. I'd prefer to do it in the style sheet I've made and not go into the actual bootstrap docs.

A good example of what I want comes straight from the Bootstrap website. How do they make the searchbox highlight in purple?

[image: When Not Selected]

[image: When Selected. How can I make it purple instead of default blue?]

Edit:

It looks like a few changes gets me closer to the result I want.

JSX:

```
<Form className='file-form col-12'>
    <input type='file' className='custom-file-input' id='batch-file'
           onChange={e => this.setState({file: e.target.files[0], fileName: e.target.files[0].name})}/>
    <label className='custom-file-label' htmlFor='customFile'>{this.state.fileName}</label>
</Form>
```

SCSS:

```
.file-form:focus, .file-form:active, .file-form:hover{
    border-color: $custom-orange;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.6) inset, 0 0 8px $custom-orange;
    //outline: 0 none;
 }
```

It works almost. There is still a blue glow once i click it.

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand. If you want to change the style of an element on focus, just use css' `:focus`, right? Why is React getting in the way of all of this?

Comment: Also pleasse provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - the component `FormGroup` is undefined

Comment: @NinoFiliu just use Form if you need to.

Comment: Please, could you tell how you solved this at the end? That would be awesome. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

add this